# mqtt get retained message or default value

Tags: java, mqtt, paho

I could use this code to get a retained message with eclipse paho:

```
    client.subscribe(myRetainedMessageTopic, (topic, message) -> {
      this.state = message.toString();
      client.unsubscribe(topic);
    });
```

However, this brings some trouble with it.

1. I have no guarantee, that myMessageTopic has a value
2. I need to somehow wait for the listeners to finish. If no value is there, they will keep in waiting state.

One easy way would be to do some trick like this:

```
    AtomicBoolean myTopicPresent = new AtomicBoolean(false);
    client.subscribe(myRetainedMessageTopic, (topic, message) -> {
      this.state = message.toString();
      myTopicPresent.set(true);
    });
    Thread.sleep(500);
    client.unsubscribe(myRetainedMessageTopic);
    if(!myTopicPresent.get()) {
      this.state = DEFAULT_STATE;
      client.publish(myRetainedMessageTopic, retainedMqttMessageWithDefaultState);
    }
```

However, this feels a bit hacky. Isn´t there a more decent way to handle such a case synchronously and more properly without some "random" timeout?